# Commandline build for android on Alpine is failing

Tags: android, linux, command-line, centos7, alpine-linux

```
NAME: "Alpine Linux"
ID: alpine
VERSION_ID : 3.18.4
PRETTY_NAME : "Alpine Linux v3.18"

Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
 Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
 Failed to transform appcompat-1.4.2.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
 Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/2dbf13ca339042497599c710c0bbe40c/transformed/appcompat-1.4.2.
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

The firewall and gate ways for downloading the decencies were unblocked

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to also open an issue in [Google's issue tracker in Android Gradle Plugin component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:192709) as the error message requests